# Supporting linux/types.h OSX

Tags: c++, macos

I am trying to cross compile an application using OSX. However, when I compile I get the following...

```
fatal error: 'linux/types.h' file not found
```

When I change to sys/types.h and now I get...

```
 error: unknown type name '__s32'
 unknown type name '__u8'
 unknown type name '__u16'
 etc
```

Can someone help me with how to handle this?

Comment: Recommendation: use `int32_t`, `uint8_t`, and `uint16_t` instead of non-portable types.

Comment: that is pretty much exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Obviously a Linux-specific header file is not going to be present under MacOS/X, which is not Linux-based.

The easiest work-around for the problem would be to go through your program and replace all the instances of

```
#include "linux/types.h"
```

with this:

```
#include "my_linux_types.h"
```

... and write a new header file named my_linux_types.h and add it to your project; it would look something like this:

```
#ifndef my_linux_types_h
#define my_linux_types_h

#ifdef __linux__
# include "linux/types.h"
#else
# include <stdint.h>
typedef int32_t __s32;
typedef uint8_t __u8;
typedef uint16_t __u16;
[... and so on for whatever other types your program uses ...]
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: Says I have to wait 20 hours to give it so you will have the bounty soon

Comment: why not use <cstdint> in the first place? since c++11 it's in the standard. Or is the application not written by the question-author?

Comment: Often when porting a program you want to change as few lines of the original codebase as you can get away with.

Answer (score 1):

Those headers are headers that the kernel uses. Probably, the problem is in the implementation  and definitions of such header files across platforms (Linux vs Mac OS in our case) The POSIX definitions don't apply to the kernel, but rather to the system calls it exposes to the user space.

Comment: I get all that and I will give you the nod if you give me a way around it. So these are defined within posix? and posix isn't supported on OSX?

Comment: These are kernel definitions (ar least, on a Linux platform that is what /linux/*.h are. They are macros that the kernel uses) For example, SIGKILL is a user space macro, that is guaranteed by POSIX/SUS to have the same value across UNIX systems. MAC OS is a certified UNIX system, which guarantees that this MACRO will have a value of 9 on all UNIX systems. Linux, on the other hand, is not a certified UNIX, but it tries to keep up with the POSIX/SUS definitions. It may be hard to make such an application like yours function on different platform, since it uses very specific platform definitions

Comment: Thanks I get all that but the underlying question was how to get them working on OSX. They may have the same value but they don't have the same name or header file. Also, OSX is certified UNIX? I thought it was based off of BSD which wasn't certified